# Using IN with LIMIT in MySql

Tags: mysql

Here is my old query which was working fine :

```
SELECT tag.tag 
FROM tag, v_bookmark_tag_assoc 
WHERE tag.tag_id = v_bookmark_tag_assoc.tag_id 
AND v_bookmark_tag_assoc.bookmark_id = '123' 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
```

Now I need to update the query to feed in all the "v_bookmark_tag_assoc.bookmark_id" as in IN clause of MySql, so that I can have all the result up in one output array for all input ids.

Problem is if if modify query like so :

```
SELECT tag.tag 
FROM tag, v_bookmark_tag_assoc 
WHERE tag.tag_id = v_bookmark_tag_assoc.tag_id 
AND v_bookmark_tag_assoc.bookmark_id IN(123,456,678,890) 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
```

It doesn't make sense at all using LIMIT of 10 for each input id is illegitimate here this way.

Please help me out to modify this query in such a way that I can have 10 tags for each input bookmark id.

Comment: Google "mysql union"...

Answer (score 1):

There are several different ways to approach to problem.  One is simply to group by the bookmarks you care about then obtain a list of tags for each - the substring_index function is being used to limit the number of tags to ten which are in ascending order.  Order and the separation character can be changed to fit your purpose.

```
select bm.bookmark_id
     , substring_index(group_concat(tag.tag order by tag.tag asc separator ','),',',10) as tag_list
  from v_bookmark_tag_assoc bm
     , tag
 where bm.bookmark_id in (123,456,678,890)
   and tag.tag_id=bm.tag_id
 group by bm.bookmark_id
```